# Should I use deploy keys with composer?

Tags: git, ssh, composer-php, gitlab

I'm using composer for two private projects for my company. Besides, we use a home-made library which is required by the both projects. To resume, there are three repos:

- library
- project1
- project2

All three repos are private and hosted on GitLab.

My problem is that while I'm working on the projects, I'm using my personal SSH key which is linked to my GitLab account to download the library. But when I want to deploy, the production server doesn't have a personal SSH key neither a GitLab account. I searched for a solution and I found this:

1. Create a read-only deploy key for the library in GitLab
2. Include the private and public in both projects
3. Edit the composer.json as following:

`"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "git@gitlab.com:{compagny}/{library}.git",
        "options": {
            "ssh2": {
                "pubkey_file": ".ssh/gitlab_{library}_id_rsa.pub",
                "privkey_file": ".ssh/gitlab_{library}_id_rsa"
            }
        }
    }
],
[...]`

Notes:

- `{}` are placeholders
- The .ssh folder is in the project roots.

But when I'm running `composer update`, I'm asked to enter GitLab credentials as regular user. How can I avoid this and use the given keys to retrieve the library code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two years later, I just figured that the **ext-ssh2** was missing and thus composer was not able to use the keys. It works now!